# Implicit arithmetic operator oracle procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've found a mistake in this oracle 11g stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE getresult (C OUT RC, code IN VARCHAR)
```

"code" input parameter has this format(year/id): `2017/000000023357`

Well, oracle makes the implicit division and the result received is that of division operation: `,0863552682279402320503489317977479984587`

Any suggestion to avoid the implicit operation instead of changing the procedure call?

Answer (score 1):

Your code parameter is `VARCHAR` and you are passing it directly without quotes. You should call it as follows.

```
EXEC getresult ( v_c , '2017/000000023357');
```

> ¿Any suggestion to avoid the implicit operation instead of changing
>   the procedure call?

why should one do that way?. You cannot expect the procedure argument to contain an arithmetic expression to be interpreted as plain text without using quotes.